# Test case for $http request using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Currently I am writing test cases in jasmine for my stand-alone angularJs app, I need to write test cases for $http requests also, I wrote the tests to match the response from $http request and $httpBackend request, but that is not enough, what else can I verify for a $http request other than response status. 
Can format of data returned be verified? and what other stuff can be checked in a test spec?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Spies: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/introduction-to-unit-test-spies/

[Spy on a service method call using jasmine Spies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658525/spy-on-a-service-method-call-using-jasmine-spies)

You can do anything with a request. You can fake all responses (success, error), fire backend requests, which are faked to local json-files and so on.

Read more about jasmine / karma testing | jasmine / karma fake backend.